# c# Highlight the rtb text colour based on regex

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox

I have question using rtb and regex together.

I have a text like `vK-lKs-812349;jra_6993788428;Enx-2674@62`

My function will split the data by deli'ter ';' and matches each part with regex patterns

- for first part `"^[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{7}$"`
- for 2nd part `"^[a-zA-Z]{3}_[0-9]{10}$"`
- for 3rd part `"^[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9&~%@*^<>!#$]{7}$"`

What I want is I have this data in line in rtb (all line have a similar data i.e, same pattern of data). When I Click a button function should get the line in which the cursor is and it should match the pattern and if regex doesn't match it should change the color of that particular part of text.

**Example**: If I'm in line 2 and the 2nd part data is 'zza 6993788428' then as there is _ missing regex will not be match so I want that this part in the rtb should get the color red.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: Thx for the edit @user861594

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox1.Text))
            {
                int lineStart = 0;
                foreach (string item in richTextBox1.Lines)
                {
                    List<string> lst = item.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToList();
                    if (lst.Count == 3)
                    {
                        if (!Regex.IsMatch(lst[1], "^[a-zA-Z]{3}_[0-9]{10}$"))
                        {
                            int Start = richTextBox1.Find(item, lineStart, richTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                            int End = Start + item.Length;

                            richTextBox1.Select(Start, End);
                            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int Start = richTextBox1.Find(item, lineStart, richTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                            int End = Start + item.Length;

                            richTextBox1.Select(Start, End);
                            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
                        }
                    }
                    lineStart += item.Length;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hey mate my question is not regarding to the regex pattern. Plzz check the question. I said if the regex pattern doesn't match with the text, then the text i.e, 'jra 6993788428' foreground color should be change to red in rtb in windows form application c#

Comment: Thx for your interest but I want the function to work in the line in which my cursor. I found the answer by my self. But I want a few improvement in my code. I want the find and replace should be happened in that particular line.

Comment: Try this  richTextBox1.Text.Replace("","")

Comment: int location = richTexBox1.Find(word, index, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            richTexBox1.Select(location, word.Length);
            richTexBox1.SelectedText = replacer;

Comment: Thx for your reply... But how to find the 'index' for the find function. I only know the line no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114343/discussion-between-roshan-and-king).

Comment: index is nothing but a starting value. In my ans (above) index is lineStart. update the index based on line length.

Comment: Hey King can you give me a code to find the index for a 3 line of rtb

Answer (score 1):

I found code for this question by myself. I created a timer that gets the line no from the rtb and puts in a global variable.

```
            timer1.Start();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(LineEvent);
```

and the global variable and events are

```
        public static class foo
    {
        public static int lineno;
    }

        private void LineEvent(object sender, EventArgs eArgs)
    {
        int IndexCoun = rtb1.SelectionStart;//Index count where actually the mouse is clicked in the richtextbox
        foo.lineno = rtb1.GetLineFromCharIndex(IndexCoun);//Get the line no
    }
```

And the main function that matches the function and changes the rtb is

```
        private void RegexCla(string value, string pattern, string data)
    {
        if(Regex.IsMatch(value, pattern) == true)
        {
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < foo.lineno; i++)
            {
                int gelen = rtb1.Lines[i].Length;
                index = index + gelen;
            }
            rtb1.Find(data, index, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
            rtb1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
            rtb1.SelectedText = value;
        }
        else
        {
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < foo.lineno; i++)
            {
                int gelen = rtb1.Lines[i].Length;
                index = index + gelen;
            }
            rtb1.Find(data, index, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
            rtb1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

And finally the button click is

```
        private void RegBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] rtblines = rtb1.Lines;
        var reqtext = rtblines[foo.lineno];
        string[] reclis = reqtext.Split(';');
        RegexCla(reclis[0].Replace(" ", ""), "^[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{7}$", reclis[0]);
    }
```

Thanks for all your support @King.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void Findword(string FindText, RichTextBox rt)
    {
        try
        {
            List<int> lst = new List<int>();
            bool IsRun = true;
            int Index = 0;
            int count =0;

            lst.Add(-1);
            lst.Add(0);
            lst.Add(rt.TextLength);
            while (IsRun)
            {
                Index = rt.Find(FindText, Index, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                if (lst.Contains(Index))
                    break;
                else
                    count++;
                lst.Add(Index);
                Index += FindText.Length;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(FindText + " Count: " + count);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @King I have fixed it mate. Thanks for all your support. Choose it as answer and ^ me if you like it. Thanks